# Spark AR Patches: switching between 3 canvas

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I have the following elements:

- Canvas1 (1 rectangle/material - *initial instructions*),
- Canvas2 (1 rectangle/material - *core image* & 1 audio with its Playback controller),
- Canvas3 (1 rectangle/material - *trivia image*).

The effect I want: when opening I see Canvas1 visible, tap 1 the Canvas2 & Audio, tap 2 the Canvas3. END

The problem: It is not working.

What happens?

- Opens as planned (Canvas1).
- On tap1 as planned (Canvas2 & Audio).
- On tap keeps Canvas 2 on the back and shows Canvas 3.
- If I tap it keeps changing between Canvas 2 and 3.

The new patches structure

- This is an image for the patches editor [image for the patches editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RJpZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simplifying the solution. I built an animation with the images (former Canvas 1, 2 and 3) inside a rectangle, and added the Audio to a tap trigger. Now it is working. Nevertheless, if somebody has an answer to why I had the problem, I very much appreciate it. 
Attached you can find the final patches configuration.[final patches configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9fWt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect the visibility of Canvas 2 to the counter value just like you did with the other ones. Check the [corrected patch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6TC1.png)